# Relational database field name design

Tags: database-design, relational-theory

Are there design patterns for naming table fields? For example, I've always used user (table)> email (field), but I see other well-used modes like user (table)> user_email (field). Are there any rules / conventions to follow?

Comment: Read, for example, [SQL Style Guide](https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/business-ops/data-team/sql-style-guide/). And remember, that none recommendation is a dogma.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum. If you do a search for `sql style guide` you will find many different ones. The key (pardon the pun :-) ) is to find one and **stick to it**. For example, I use `python_case_for_variable_names` (table and column names) and upper case for SQL KEYWORDS and I keep table names singular. Simple and it really helps when re-reading old code!

Comment: @Vinícius Guerato - I deal with this ALL the time. It basically comes down to preference, and what will work for you and your project / organization. I've actually referenced this document for documents I've written for customers.https://www.isbe.net/Documents/SQL_server_standards.pdf - CamelCase, read ability are the ones I almost always use / implement on the projects I work on.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter what naming convention you use, however it is really important to have one and stick to it. As long as you're strict about using it, you'll have a clean/readable database.

A couple of useful tips:

- Using tbl_xx or v_ for tables/views might be a bad idea, cause tomorrow, you might change the view to a table or visa versa. Which could end up being really confusing a couple of years from now.
- Try to give meaningful names to columns, for example an email field should not be named user_e, but user_email, or just email.
- Correct use of underscores or capitalization, bigfieldbuthardtoread vs BigFieldButEasyToRead vs Big_Field_But_Easy_To_Read
- Don't prefix procedures with sp_, can cause some performance issues (it will first look in the master for that sp)

If you don't want to make up your own system, you can always try to find one online and make that your own, for example [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1065295/SQL-Server-Table-and-Column-Naming-Conventions) one